# Unable to delete page in Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I'm trying to delete a page from Pages application and I'm receiving success message

[image]

But the page is still there.

It's the same when I try to delete a page from JCR, I'm receiving success message, but the node is still there.

I have no info, warning or error messages in the logs.

What I've tried is to turn off the public instance from the Configuration app, but still I'm not able to delete a page.

It's happening only on my author instance.

Any idea, where I can look to find some info why I'm unable to delete a page, or why I have that problem?

Thanks.

Edit:
I don't get the trash bin icon on the page like this:
[image]

Just nothing is happening.

Solution:
Ok, I kinda solve it.

This is happening only on macOS Mojave in Safari 12.1.1
It works fine on Windows under Chrome, Firefox, Edge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish the deleted page. The activation/deactivation of pages does not happen automatically, so if the node disappears immediately after deletion, you won't be able afterwards to publish the "deletion" to public instances, to keep them in sync.

Comment: I don't get the trash bin icon, to be able to publish the deletion, just nothing is happening.

Comment: @rainxart is this happening for every node or only on specific node. if happens only on one specific node than probably node is corrupted and you can try to delete it with groovy script

Comment: The "test" page you show in the screenshot has a trash bin icon. It is already deleted. Now you just need to publish deletion for the page to disappear.

Comment: @Jan this was just an example, what I want to achieve. I found that this behaviour is only under macOS Mojave, Safari 12.1.1